# expressão is null sendo inserido no select das relações no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho 2 models:

**Campanhas.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Campanhas extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_pagina',
        'id_dominio',
        'titulo',
    ];

    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    const CREATED_AT = 'data_criacao';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'data_atualizacao';
    const DELETED_AT = 'data_exclusao';

    public function grupos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Grupos::class, 'id_campanha', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Grupos.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Grupos extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'id_whitelabel',
        'id_conta',
    ];

    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    const CREATED_AT = 'data_criacao';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'data_atualizacao';
    const DELETED_AT = 'data_exclusao';
}
```

Estou fazendo uma seleção no laravel assim:

```
$grupos = $this->campanhas->grupos();
```

Mas não está me retornando nenhum resultado, mas tenho dados relacionados corretamente. Fui dar uma olhada na query que ele está realizando por trás e me deparei com a seguinte query:

```
select * from `grupos` where `grupos`.`id_campanha` is null and `grupos`.`id_campanha` is not null and `grupos`.`data_exclusao` is null
```

Como pode-se notar, ele está inserindo **grupos.id_campanha is null and grupos.id_campanha is not null** e por esse motivo ele não está conseguindo trazer os dados corretamente. Se retirar o **grupos.id_campanha is null** então ele trás os resultados corretamente.

Por curiosidade fui buscando no código fonte do laravel o que poderia ser, e achei em *Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é essa parte desse código que está adicionando o *is null* e também o *is not null* . Como poderia resolver esse problema e fazer a seleção normal ?

Comment: tente: $grupos = $this->campanhas->grupos()->get();

Answer (score -2, accepted):

consegui achar o problema!

Para quem for útil:

O problema estava acontecendo pela forma que eu estava fazendo a consulta. Eu estava tentando fazer assim:

```
$grupos = $this->campanhas->grupos()->where('id_campanha', '=', 'abc123');
```

Mas no caso eu precisava primeiro capturar a campanha e depois puxar os grupos, fazendo a consulta assim:

```
$grupos = $this->campanhas->where('id', '=', 'abc123')->grupos();
```

ou

```
$grupos = $this->campanhas->find('abc123')->grupos();
```

A ordem da consulta importa para fazer tal busca. Outra alternativa, mas que para mim não era legal seria fazer assim:

```
$grupos = $this->campanhas::with('grupos')->whereHas('grupos', function($query)){
    $query->where('id_campanha', '=', 'abc123');
}
```

Dessa última forma o código fica grande demais na minha opinião, por isso estava tentando buscar uma alternativa mais correta.